# Help understand the definition of random measure

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Here is from [the wikipedia page on random measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure), and I want to understand the highlighted part. $M_X$ is the set of all bounded finite measures on ${\cal B} (X)$, then what is $\Omega$ here?

Based on my understanding, random measure is a measure-valued random variable, for example, a random variable distributed according to Dirichlet distribution, how does this intuitive thing fit into the definition?

[image]

Comment: The text is considering a mapping $$\mu:\Omega\to M_X$$ thus, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, $\mu(\omega)$ is a finite measure on $\mathfrak B(X)$ (that is, to be sure one gets the point, $\mu(\omega)(B)$ is a **real number**, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and every $B$ in $\mathfrak B(X)$).

Comment: To be fair, one wonders what the paragraph "A measure generally might be decomposed as..." is doing here. Might be reminiscent of previous versions of the page.